# Displaying NULL in ng-grid for angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

ngGrid is converting my NULL cells to 0 or an empty string ("") based on the column type. 
I need this displayed as 'NULL' instead. What is an *efficient way* to do this? There could be 10,000+ rows of data displayed in the Grid.

Simple Plunker displaying **undesired** behaviour:
http://plnkr.co/edit/MwAotQ?p=preview

(notice 0, "", or $0.00 instead of NULL).

Thanks!

->> Josh <<-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a custom filter that extends the original filter.  Here is how you would do it for your date column:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'myData',
        columnDefs: [{ field: "name", width: 120 },
                    { field: "age", width: 120, cellFilter: 'number' },
                    { field: "birthday", width: 120, cellFilter: 'nullDateFilter' },
                    { field: "salary", width: 120, cellFilter: 'currency'  }]
    };
    $scope.myData = [{ name: "Moroni", age: 50, birthday: "Oct 28, 1970", salary: 60000 },
                    { name: "Tiancum", age: 43, birthday: "Feb 12, 1985", salary: 70000 },
                    { name: "Jacob", age: 27, birthday: "Aug 23, 1983", salary: 50000 },
                    { name: null, age: null, birthday: null, salary: null },
                    { name: "Enos", age: 34, birthday: "Aug 3, 2008", salary: 30000 }];
});

app.filter('nullDateFilter', function($filter) {
  return function(input) {
    var originalFilter = $filter('date');
    return input == null ? 'null' : originalFilter(input);
  };
});
```